# `rename': Permission denied @ sys_fail2

Tags: ruby, powershell, installation, devkit

```
PS C:\Users\Roman> ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3'
dk.rb:86:in `rename': Permission denied @ sys_fail2 - (C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb, C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defau
lts/operating_system.rb.20141106064922) (Errno::EACCES)
        from dk.rb:86:in `update_gem_override'
        from dk.rb:260:in `block (2 levels) in install'
        from dk.rb:246:in `each'
        from dk.rb:246:in `block in install'
        from dk.rb:219:in `each'
        from dk.rb:219:in `install'
        from dk.rb:313:in `run'
        from dk.rb:332:in `<main>'
```

Trying to install the devkit. "ruby dk.rb init" went without a hitch. Then this happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is a problem with Ruby being installed to C:\Program Files\ without administator priviledges. For some reason, a copy of Ruby exists in my version of Heroku. This is autodetected by the devkit, and when it tries to install it there, it fails.

When `ruby dk.rb init` executes, a YAML file is created, called config.yaml, and all the paths of detected version of Ruby are added to it. By opening config.yaml and editing out the Heroku path, the problem was solved.

I hope this is helpful for other users.

Found the help I needed [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/246#issuecomment-61905721).

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as an administrator and then run ruby dk.rb install command where have you extracted Devkit.

To run cmd as an administator:

1. type cmd in start menu
2. right click cmd.exe
3. click Run as administrator.

After successful completion of command, you will see something like below:

> [INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Hero
>   ku/ruby-2.1.7'
>   [INFO] Installing 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/d
>   evkit.rb'